# Is ULP Video Streaming Sampler support the mp4 video format?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, ubikloadpack

In jmeter Threadgroup 
When i enter a Video URL in ULP Video Streaming Sampler and when i click on Playlist i am getting the Error like : URL does not contain a valid Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

[UbikLoadPack](https://ubikloadpack.com/video-streaming-performance.php) Video Streaming supports:

- HLS
- MPEG-DASH / Dash
- Smooth /HSS
- HDS

Both Live and VOD.

Those are known as adaptive video streaming formats.

I think what you mention through mp4 is Progressive download, and it is not supported by UbikLoadPack.

Feel free to reach our support to have more information and help.

Note regarding the open source, we are a strong contributor to Apache JMeter since years now, you can check our contributions at:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html
- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html

Comment: Then is there any plugins that will support the mp4 video streaming to test in jmeter load